# NFC communicate with existing RFID

Tags: java, android, symbian, nfc, rfid

Is it possible to create an application  utilizing NFC(Near field Communication) of mobile phone  which will communicate with existing RFID infrastructure ?Have both in the same frequency range? I read in an article that says RFID has a High Frequency (HF) band at 13.56 MHz and that have longer communication range. I confused that  NFC has the same frequency limit but short communication range;how it possible?Does NFC support all RFID technologies 
( both active and passive RFID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes. But only passive RFID technology. Check out this [package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary.html). Also this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_18000-3). Both RFID and NFC work over same frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Symbian Anna implements NFC via the JSR-257. Not sure if it allows reading RFID. Check this link for more info:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/nfc/